# java script loop , carousel image div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

html carousel static code working fine, but when I append the div using java script loop it showing in vertical line. below is my html static code

```
<section id="feature" class="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="rest-head">
          <p><span class="h-3 gray">Name</span></p>
          <p><span class="h-4 gray">text</span></p>
        </div>

          <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-cell"><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a>
            <div class="slide-footer">
            <span><h5 class="nomargin ellipsis">text</h5></span>
            <h5 class="pull-left">text</h5>
            <h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>price</strong></h5>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell"><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a>
            <div class="slide-footer">
            <span><h5 class="nomargin ellipsis">text</h5></span>
            <h5 class="pull-left">text</h5>
            <h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>price</strong></h5>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell"><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a>
            <div class="slide-footer">
            <span><h5 class="nomargin ellipsis">text</h5></span>
            <h5 class="pull-left">text</h5>
            <h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>price</strong></h5>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell"><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a>
            <div class="slide-footer">
            <span><h5 class="nomargin ellipsis">text</h5></span>
            <h5 class="pull-left">text</h5>
            <h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>price</strong></h5>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell"><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a>
            <div class="slide-footer">
            <span><h5 class="nomargin ellipsis">text</h5></span>
            <h5 class="pull-left">text</h5>
            <h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>price</strong></h5>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </section>
```

---

**here is my java script code,when I appending the image div it coming up vertically**

```
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    returnResult='<div class="carousel-cell">';
    returnResult+='<a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>';
    returnResult+='<div class="slide-footer"><span><h5 class="nomargin 
    ellipsis">';
    returnResult+= name1;
    returnResult+='</h5></span><h5 class="pull-left">'+name2+'%</h5>';
    returnResult+='<h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr">';
    returnResult+=name3+'</strong></h5></div></div></div>'; 
    $(".carousel").append(returnResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is initialize the carousel after you have appended the dynamic divs into the carousel class:

add the following code after the for loop in your code:

```
$(".carousel").carousel();
```

So your code becomes:

```
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    returnResult='<div class="carousel-cell">';
    returnResult+='<a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>';
    returnResult+='<div class="slide-footer"><span><h5 class="nomargin 
    ellipsis">';
    returnResult+= name1;
    returnResult+='</h5></span><h5 class="pull-left">'+name2+'%</h5>';
    returnResult+='<h5 class="pull-right"><strong><i class="fa fa-inr">';
    returnResult+=name3+'</strong></h5></div></div></div>'; 
    $(".carousel").append(returnResult);
    }
$(".carousel").carousel();
```